# Finding file location with a given string in it in Linux

Tags: grep, location

There are multiple files with name "log.xml" at various locations in my file system in Linux.

I need to find the exact location of one "log.xml" file having string "Hello World!" in it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As always, `find` is the usual but irritating answer.

```
/home/user1326379> find / -name "log.xml" -exec grep -I -l -s \ 
                   'Hello World!' {} \;
```

The `grep` options are to ignore binary files, to just print the file names of matching files, and to be silent for read errors in OSX.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -l 'pattern' /parentPath/**/log.xml
```